# OpenJDK and OpenJFX on Linux mint 19 (tara)

Tags: openjfx

I'm trying to run a program that requires Java FX.  I just installed Linux Mint (Tara) Cinnamon.  It has OpenJDK installed.
openjdk version "10.0.2" 2018-07-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 10.0.2+13-Ubuntu-1ubuntu0.18.04.3)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 10.0.2+13-Ubuntu-1ubuntu0.18.04.3, mixed mode)

I also installed openJFX.  Re-running apt-get install openjfx produces:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
openjfx is already the newest version (8u161-b12-1ubuntu2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

When I try to run the application, I get the following error:
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: I would love to know that as well.

Comment: Did you manage to solve the problem?

Comment: No.  I had ended up installing the Oracle Java which worked for the program I was trying to run.